# Private/Hiding dependencies between Maven modules

Tags: java, design, dependencies, modules, maven

Given three project modules **X**, **Y** and **Z** on a Maven based project, and **Y** depends of **Z** and **X** of **Y** and **X** should not know that **Y** depends of **Z**, being this:

**X** -> **Y**

**Y** -> **Z**

**X** -X> **Z**

What is the best way to hide the dependency between modules **X** and **Z** ?

I'm aware that on Maven it's possible to change the scope of the dependency, but I would like to know if there are any other options for it

Comment: What do you mean by X not knowing about the dependency between Y and Z? Should the fact that Z exists be completely hidden from users/developers of X, or do you just want to avoid having to declare a dependency between X and Z, something else?

Comment: Users/Developers of X should not know about Z existence @BartvanIngenSchenau

Comment: What is the relationship between Y and Z? Is Z just needed to build Y, or does the produced Y.jar also depend on Z.jar to be able to execute?

Comment: Y depends in any form of Z, as an example we can say that Z is the core of the project

We could say Y is the application controller and X is the front-end

Comment: Then you are probably out of luck. You can't hide the existence of Z, because of the simple fact that if it is missing from the installation, then the application won't work.

Comment: Well that's really unfortunate :\ Thanks for the answers though!

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I've found a way of "making things work" on project POM's but for me it looks like a very unpleasant solution.


Basically by setting the Z dependency as optional (or exclude it) on Y module, and adding the Z dependency with the scope only for runtime, X will not have access to it (classpath on compile), yet it will be included during runtime

Comment: I'm mostly curious about the reason of "hiding" a dependency.

Comment: hey @dagnelies, answering your question, it's most for not allowing developers to fall on the risk of using directly the core module, when there is an application module which is available for everyone that communicates with the core module

Comment: @SEISCOOL In this case, you often want to split the API from the implementation. For instance, you can create the module `foo-api` which contains the interface `FooService`, but no implementation. Then, you can create the module `foo-core`, which depends on `foo-api` and provide the implementation `ActualFooService`. Then, if you have another project `bar` which requires to talk to the `FooService`, you only make it depend on `foo-api`. In this case, you can't use any `foo-core` classes from `bar` because it does not know it exists, it only knows the public API.

Comment: @SEISCOOL I was in the same situation, and refactoring was out of scope, so your solution came in handy. Perhaps you should consider making it an answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want the programmers of X to use classes of Z. You can achieve this with the Maven dependency plugin:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-only-mojo.html

This allows you to fail the build if somebody uses a class from an artifact that is not declared as dependency in their own POM.